# If someone takes a photo of my product and posts it on the web do I have the right to use it on my website?

Tags: images, photo, copyright

If someone takes a photo of my product and posts it on the web do I have the right to use it on my website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily, as the "work", for copyright purposes, is the picture of the product and not the product.

Peace and Grace,
Gregory A. Beamer

Comment: Pretty much how ebay works.  Say you are selling your Levi pants on ebay, you can't use a picture from Levi.com, but you can take a picture of your Levi pants with your own camera, and post it in your listing.

Answer (score 1):

If I've been selling the product, I always drop the people who produce the product a courtesy email asking permission, no one has ever said no and many have volunteered high quality images of their own to help us out.